# Ignore Laravel observer for a specific save method

Tags: php, laravel-4, observers

Can I ignore an observer for a specific save method called?

I have this in the observer:

```
public function saved(Item $item){
    // event stuff
    $event->save();
}
```

Then I call a save method on the Item class:

```
public function update_item_notes()
{
    // item stuff
    $item->save();
}
```

The method is just to update the row, but the save observer is for when a new row is created...

Currently when updating the row in my method it calls the save observer...

Comment: Are you aware of the `push()` method in Eloquent if you’re wanting to save a row and its relations?

Answer (score 1):

You can ignore the observer by  using withoutEvents  and saveQuietly  methods see the documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#observers)

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30881979)

Answer (score 0):

There are three model events

`creating` and `created`: called for new data only

`updating` and `updated`: called for update data only

`saving` and `saved`: called when both new and updated data

So change your model event from `saved()` to `created()` and it will only be called for new rows.